# about the global variable in tcl

Tags: tcl, global

I have a question about global variable in TCL:

```
set gvar "abc"

proc justTest {} {
    global gvar
    puts $global
}
```

if a variable is declared in global space, we should use `global` keyword to access the global variable inside a proc, but if where is no global variable is declared, but we use `global` keyword inside a function, what will happen? for example:

#### no global variable is declared

```
proc justTest {} {
        global gvar
        set here $gvar
        puts $here
    }
```

then what will happen?

Comment: Quite often, the best way to answer "what will happen" is to simply try it and see. You'll get your answer quicker than waiting for someone on the internet.

Comment: ...especially using [the right tool for the job](http://tkcon.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Case 1: you are referencing the global variable

In this case, you are using its value, but not setting it. You don't have to set the global variable `gvar` before **defining** your proc. You only need to set `gvar` before **calling** your proc. Failure to set `gvar` before hand will cause error.

#### Case 2: you set the value of the global variable

In this case, you don't need to create the global variable before calling your proc. After calling your proc, the global variable will be created and available.

Answer (score 2):

Same as if you tried to access a local variable that was never declared.

```
can't read "gvar": no such variable
```

On a related note, if you `set` the variable from within the proc, you *would* be able to access it from the main scope (after calling the proc of course).

Comment: @ratzip, note that `global` only *declares* a variable, not creates it. More precisely, in a special table of variables available in the current scope (procedure in your case), `global` creates a special "link" entry which points to the similar table in the global scope. Then all accesseses to that local entry are transparently redirected to the linked global entry. Hence, after `global` finished, all the stuff like existence/value is defined by the linked-to variable.